# How do I pass a RegEx pattern to Pytesseract?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

There seems to be two ways to go about this, none seem to work.

First, you can pass `tessedit_char_whitelist`, but that seems to work only with characters, not patterns:

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\.../tesseract.exe'

pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config="-c tessedit_char_whitelist=.{5,15}\d{4,8}")
```

That doesn't work, although you can whitelist characters as `'abcdefgh'`.

The second way is [this way](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc#config-files-and-augmenting-with-user-data). I have found the `eng.user-patterns` file, and entered my RegEx pattern, but I don't know how to set it so it's active. I guess it would be something like:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img, configfile="eng.user-patterns")
```

However, `pytesseract` accepts no such argument.

Answer (score 0):

RegEx are not supported by tesseract and pytesseract can do nothing with it.
tessedit_char_whitelist and user-patterns are different parameter with different effects.